# What timing settings in VirtualDub should be used for VHS capture via EasyCap?

Tags: video-capture, virtualdub, vhs, pal

I want to digitize my VHS (PAL) home video tapes using an old video cassette player and EasyCap. Here is the photo of my EasyCap chips for reference:

[image]

After several days of reading how to perform video capture properly I found the VirtualDub most suitable. But I am completely lost in timing options. How to set them properly?

[image]

Please give some suggestions.
Especially unclear:

- Is there sense in "Drop frames..." and "Insert null frames..." options or of I just can tick "Correct video timing..." while using "Sync audio to video..."?
- On the other hand maybe that is better to sync video to audio?
- Should I use audio/video sync at all?
- Should I tick "Use audio timestamps..."?
- Should I use automatic audio latency compensation?

I'll appreciate any advice on all the options of the timing dialog.

Comment: see 11.10 quite a usefull guide using Virtual Dub , if you want to convert PAL ignore the NSTC stuff https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sn_TDa9zY1c&t=936s